# JS+Regexp: Match anything except if it's between [[ ]]

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a `<textarea>` that will be basically a list of names, so I set a function to replace the spaces between the names for a new line.

Now I need to specify that two or more spaces between names are in fact part of the same element.
IE:

```
John Lucas [[Laurie Vega]] [[Daniel Deer]] Robert
```

Should turn to

```
John
Lucas
[[Laurie Vega]]
[[Daniel Deer]]
Robert
```

So now my regexp `$("textarea").val().toString().replace(\ \g, '\n');` is broken as it will add a new line before Vega and Deer.

I need to replace anything that's not in between `[` and `]`. I just made the opposite and tried to negate it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
// Works
$("textarea").val().toString().match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g));
// Am I using the ! operand wrong?
$("textarea").val().toString().match(/!\[([^\]]*)\]/g));
```

I'm a little lost. I tried matching and then replacing, but that way I won't be able to recover my original string. So I have to match anything outside double brackets and replace the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a chance that your names contain non alphabetic characters ("Jim-bo O'Leary"?), you may prefer match anything that is not a '[' or a space using /[^[ ]/.

You can then join the matched strings to get the new line effect.

```
$("textarea").val().toString().match(/([^\[ ]+|\[\[[^\]]*\]\])/g).join("\n");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! (Just a small typo: match closes twice)

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation point has no particular meaning in a regex.

What you're looking for is *either* (that means the `|` operator) a sequence of letters

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

or two brackets, followed by some non-closing-brackets, followed by two closing brackets

```
\[\[[^\]]+\]\]
```

So

```
$("textarea").val().toString().match(/[A-Za-z]+|\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/g)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to replace, not to match.